# elsarticle two column text infringe to abstract

Tags: two-column, templates, elsarticle

I found no template for Elsevier Expert Systems with Applications therefore, I tried to edit Procedia template. I have a problem

- The text has infringed to the line below abstract and keywords.

.

```
\documentclass[3p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{ecrc}
\volume{00}

\firstpage{1}

\journal{Expert Systems with Applications}

\runauth{Me et al.}

%% The choice of journal logo is determined by the \jid and \jnltitlelogo commands.
%% A user-supplied logo with the name <\jid>logo.pdf will be inserted if present.
%% e.g. if \jid{yspmi} the system will look for a file yspmilogo.pdf
%% Otherwise the content of \jnltitlelogo will be set between horizontal lines as a default logo

%% Give the abbreviation of the Journal.
\jid{eswa}

%% Give a short journal name for the dummy logo (if needed)

%\jnltitlelogo{images/logo/logo-expert-systems-with-applications.gif}
\jnltitlelogo{Expert Systems with Applications}

%% Hereafter the template follows `elsarticle'.
%% For more details see the existing template files elsarticle-template-harv.tex and elsarticle-template-num.tex.



\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}


\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\dochead{}

\title{title title title title title title }

\author{author1}
\author{author2}
\author{author3}
\address{address1}
\address{address2}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[75]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,key6
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{first section}

\lipsum[3-10]


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\bibliography{optimizing_horizon_ref}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where does one find `ecrc.sty`?

Comment: @Werner, The link [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions#crc) is broken. So, I downloaded it from [University of Chicago](http://psec.uchicago.edu/library/data/ANL_APS_Data/APSpapers/TIPP/ecrc.sty).

Comment: @Werner, even the one [here](https://github.com/aignas/LaTeX-project/tree/master/publishing/pub-elsevier/template/crc) has the same problem.

Comment: @Werner, the link from you is a single column template with no similarity to the published elsevier papers.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the right side of the page with a title"?

Comment: I think you should ask your editor how to submit your content. Elsevier will process your content in a different way anyway.

Comment: A [link](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/preparing-crc-journal-articles-with-latex) to the download page for `ecrc.sty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the `3p` document class option, there is a default `\vspace*{-20pt}` inserted after creating the title. Strange, but true. You can just negate this via an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\vspace*{-20pt}\fi}{\fi}{}{}%
}
```